# Removing duplicate entries while retaining unique information

Tags: r, duplicates, unique

I have a dataset with multiple rows, which is a database of contact details. Some entries are repeated several times, but contain different information. Example:

```
> example
     Title             Name              Email         Phone      
[1,] "Chair"           "Oswald Gruber"   "abc@abc.com" "+33 12345"
[2,] "Respondent"      "Oswald Gruber"   NA            "+44 54321"
[3,] "Comm.mngr"       "Kaspar Villiger" "qwe@rty.com" "+1 123456"
[4,] "Investment mngr" "Markus Urben"    "jkl@jkl.com" NA         
[5,] "Responsible"     "Markus Urben"    "jkl@jkl.com" "+1 33333"
```

So what I'd like is to have each person mentioned only once, but without losing the info. So, if I merge two first rows in this example, I'd like to retain the email address and both phone numbers, but only one kind of title.

I would appreciate if anybody would suggest any solutions.

Comment: Which Title do you want to retain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And a data.table solution:

```
library(data.table)
mrg <- function(x) paste(unique(x[!is.na(x)]),collapse=", ")
setDT(example)[,list(Title=head(Title,1), Email=mrg(Email), Phone=mrg(Phone)), by="Name"]

#               Name           Title       Email                Phone
# 1:   Oswald Gruber           Chair abc@abc.com +33 12345, +44 54321
# 2: Kaspar Villiger       Comm.mngr qwe@rty.com            +1 123456
# 3:    Markus Urben Investment mngr jkl@jkl.com             +1 33333
```

This returns the first Title in the natural order, which may or may not be what you want. It also consolidates emails properly and removes NAs.

Comment: any ideas why it throws at me `Error: unexpected ']' in "setDT(dat)`?

Comment: `dat` is same as `example`, the whole line of code is then `Error: unexpected ']' in "setDT(example)[,list(Title=head(Title,1), Email=mrg(Email), Phone=mrg(Phone)), by="Name"]"`

Comment: Never mind, it works now. The only thing is that some of my data don't have Names, just Emails, so I'm thinking what's the best way to go. So far I've just split into two: with and without.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your "example" object is a data.frame (may also work with a matrix).
For those columns you want to retain all the information, you could do this (untested for coding typos):

```
result <- aggregate(example[,c("Phone","Email")], by = list(Name = example[,"Name"]), FUN = paste, sep = ", ")
```

Thus phone numbers and eMail adresses will be pasted into single columns as string elements, the values being separated by comas). 
Alternatively,

```
result <- aggregate(example[,c("Phone","Email")], by = list(Name = example[,"Name"]), FUN = c)
```

will give 2 columns containing list of vectors of length = the number of entries for a particular Name.

For the columns you want to retain just one value, well you have to specify which you want. If it's always the first value to come, that would be

```
result2 <- aggregate(example[,"title"], by = list(Name = example[,"Name"]), function(x) x[1])
```

And then you can

```
merged <- merge(results, result2)
```

Comment: Any ideas on why it aggregates in this format: `c("Pension Fund Manager", "Pension Fund Manager")` and how to get rid of it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Could you develop with an example?

Answer (score 1):

You can group by `Name` and convert each column to a list.

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% group_by(Name) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(list)) -> res
```

So, it looks like

```
data.frame(res)
#              Name                        Title                    Email
# 1 Kaspar Villiger                    Comm.mngr              qwe@rty.com
# 2    Markus Urben Investment mngr, Responsible jkl@jkl.com, jkl@jkl.com
# 3   Oswald Gruber            Chair, Respondent          abc@abc.com, NA
#                  Phone
# 1            +1 123456
# 2         NA, +1 33333
# 3 +33 12345, +44 54321
```

I don't know what further modifications you want, but you could easily remove NA values/duplicates and choose to only keep one Title with a slight change to the code.  For example, to remove NA/duplicates, you could use `funs(list(unique(na.omit(.))))`.

Comment: OP asked for only one Title. How would you modify your code to do this? thx

Comment: The thing about this solution is that it returns the same email multiple times (see Markus Urban record), and returns NAs, which is probably not warranted (see Gruber record).

Comment: @jlhoward yea, the `funs` function can be anything though, so whatever data cleaning is wanted can just be added there.

Comment: @pcantalupo well, you could choose to either 1) not apply list to that column, or 2) select the first element of each entry after the fact

Comment: using the newest version of tidyr, this is just `dat %>% nest(-Name)`

Comment: @nongkrong This aborts the session when I'm trying to execute it :(

Comment: @jeremycg I've just updated my packages, and there is no `nest` function

Comment: you need to install the [dev version from github](https://github.com/hadley/tidyr)

Answer (score -2):

I'd split it out into a relational database. This is assuming that names can serve as a unique key to identify a person.

```
library(dplyr)

test = 
  data_frame(
    Title = c("Chair", "Respondent", "Comm.mngr", "Investment mngr", "Responsible"),
    Name = c("Oswald Gruber", "Oswald Gruber", "Kaspar Villiger", "Markus Urben", "Markus Urben"),
    Email = c("abc@abc.com", NA, "qwe@rty.com", "jkl@jkl.com", "jkl@jkl.com"),
    Phone = c("+33 12345", "+44 54321", "+1 123456", NA, "+1 33333") )

Person__Title = 
  test %>%
  select(Name, Title) %>%
  distinct %>%
  filter(!is.na(Title))

Person__Phone =
  test %>%
  select(Name, Phone) %>%
  distinct %>%
  filter(!is.na(Phone))

Person__Email = 
  test %>%
  select(Name, Email) %>%
  distinct %>%
  filter(!is.na(Email))

Person = 
  test %>%
  select(Name) %>%
  distinct
```

Then, if you want to merge it all together, you could do

```
make_list = function(vector)
  vector %>%
  unique %>%
  na.omit %>%
  paste(collapse = ", ")

merge = 
  Person %>%
  left_join(Person__Email) %>%
  left_join(Person__Phone) %>%
  left_join(Person__Title) %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(make_list))
```

But I wouldn't recommend it. Having multiple pieces of information in the same cell goes against the principles of good data design.